# KVM Virtualization Server - One physical disk(SSD) every virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, performance, kvm-virtualization

In terms of performance,
is it better to have one "big" SSD disk for several (lets say 5) virtualized guests,
or a single smaller SSD disk for every virtual machine?

any general draw back having small disks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess it's not the disk itself that may be a performance bottleneck when multiple VMs will perform intensive disk operations simultaneously. It's the disk **controller** (or **host adapter**, to be precise).

If you have multiple disks on a single controller, it will impact performance in a similar way as if it were a single disk. It will be better than single disk, however not very much in my opinion.

And the possibility to add additional disk controllers is hardware dependent of course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, then if i find out that my server hardware have multiple host adapter, and I attach a single SSD to every host adapter, that should be the most performant option? 

I understand that it's possible to attach multiple disk to a single host adapter, that's what should be avoided. Is it also possible the opposite? : example using LVM to create separate block devices on the virtualization server, and configuring single guest vm to use different host adapter(each one it's dedicated one), to write into the same physical disk?

Comment: Different host adapters connected to single disk it's usually an impossible configuration without a SAN. Even if it is possible, it wouldn't make much sense as single disk will slow the I/O as well as single host adapter. Multiple host adapters with a disk connected to each one, each dedicated to one VM seems to be the best option.

Comment: thank you for the clarification man, very helpfull